# NextJs 13, Link component incorrectly works in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having trouble with Link component in NextJs version 13, specifically with **aria-current** attribute. I use NextIntl library to switch languages, and it works fine in development mode. The problem lies when I try to build and start project in production. When I use any languages other than default one, it works fine, aria-current attribute is added initially, and current page is highlighted thanks to CSS. But when I switch to default locale, on initial render it suddenly stops working, until I redirect to any other page. Can someone explain, what is wrong?

Code of Link component:

```
"use client";

import React, { ComponentProps, PropsWithChildren, useCallback } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { isNotEmpty, resultIf } from "@/src/shared/utils";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useLocale } from "use-intl";
import { defaultUserLocale } from "@/src/shared/models/enums";

export type ProjectLinkProps = ComponentProps<typeof Link> & {
    explicitActive?: boolean;
};

function ProjectLink(
    { href, children, explicitActive, ...props }: PropsWithChildren<ProjectLinkProps>,
    ref: ProjectLinkProps["ref"]
) {
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const locale = useLocale();
    const getLocalizedHref = useCallback(
        (originalHref: string) => {
            if (locale === defaultUserLocale) {
                return originalHref;
            }
            return originalHref.replace(/^\//, `/${locale}/`);
        },
        [locale]
    );

    const localizedHref =
        typeof href === "string"
            ? getLocalizedHref(href)
            : isNotEmpty(href.pathname)
            ? { ...href, pathname: href.pathname.replace(/^\//, `/${locale}/`) }
            : href;
    return (
        <Link
            {...props}
            ref={ref}
            href={localizedHref}
            aria-current={resultIf(pathname === localizedHref || explicitActive, "page")}
        >
            {children}
        </Link>
    );
}

export default React.forwardRef(ProjectLink);
```

How it looks with secondary language on initial render (url is http://localhost:3003/ru/subscriptions):

[image]

And here is version with default 'en' locale (http://localhost:3003/subscriptions):

[image]